# Error: Please specify the prefix where libmemcached headers are located

Tags: memcached, pear, pecl

I am trying to install memcached with Pecl and Pear. When I run this command

```
Abrams-MacBook-Air-3:recurly abramhandler$ sudo pecl install memcached --with-libememcached-dir=/usr/lib/libmemcached-1.0.17/libmemcached
```

I get the following error

```
checking for libmemcached location... configure: error: memcached support requires libmemcached 1.0.x. Use --with-libmemcached-dir=<DIR> to specify the prefix where libmemcached headers and library are located
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/memcached/configure' failed
```

This dir contains a lot of header files, but seems to maybe be the wrong one?

```
/usr/lib/libmemcached-1.0.17/libmemcached
```

What headers is memcached looking for? What directory should I include in the install command?

Answer (score 0):

pecl does not allow passing configuration arguments when compiling extensions.

You have to extract the archive yourself and do the installation yourself, too. Instructions can be found on http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/phpfarm-install-extensions.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can pass configuration options like:

```bash
pecl install -D 'with-php-config="/usr/local/bin/php-config" with-libmemcached-dir="/usr"  with-zlib-dir="no" enable-memcached-msgpack="no" enable-memcached-json="no"  with-system-fastlz="no" enable-memcached-igbinary="yes" enable-memcached-protocol="yes" enable-memcached-sasl="yes" enable-memcached-session="yes"' memcached
```